# C# - TabControl TabPage's SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I have a program that has a tabControl in it, with a few TabPages and a few stuff on the out side of it.

I want to program a TabControl SelectedIndex Change or something like that.... What I want it to do is this:

I have two TabPages, if tabPage1 is selected then it enables some groupboxes on the outside of the TabControl (in the same Form), if tabPage2 is selected then the enable groupboxes = false. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: No one will write code for you for free. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the selectedindexchanged event

```
private void TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       MessageBox.Show("You are in the TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged event.");    
}
```

and check what the current index is from the sender object

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That's not what I am trying to do - I want an If statement - when you change a tabPage1 to tabPage2 then selected stuff are Disabled, then stwitching from tabPage2 to tabPage1 selected items are enabled

Comment: I'm teaching you to fish...